# ItemDataBound in A Datalist in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

After reading [Formatting the DataList and Repeater Based Upon Data (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/formatting-the-datalist-and-repeater-based-upon-data-cs) on Microsoft Website I found the following code sample.

```
protected void ItemDataBoundFormattingExample_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Programmatically reference the ProductsRow instance bound
        // to this DataListItem
        Northwind.ProductsRow product =
            (Northwind.ProductsRow)((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;
        // See if the UnitPrice is not NULL and less than $20.00
        if (!product.IsUnitPriceNull() && product.UnitPrice < 20)
        {
            // TODO: Highlight the product's name and price
        }
    }
}
```

However in the above I would like to know where Northwind.ProductsRow product is coming from. Is it from the Northwind database name or somewhere else.

Comment: What do you mean? It's a class defined in C# code, representing a data structure. And you see how the data read from the database is casted, right?

Comment: Anyhow. Why are you looking at this? This is really REALLY old stuff (webforms) which isn't even supported anymore.

Comment: link here in regards to the BIG NEWS for vs2022, and that they 100% re-done the web forms desinger - all based on chrome, and now with live data preview. So, this huge news of a whole new web forms desinger - BIG BIG news, and shows that web forms are not dead, are they??? Link here:  -- "Design your Web Forms apps with Web Live Preview in Visual Studio 2022: -- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/

Comment: @JHBonarius
I asked because I have a datalist diplaying contents in my website. The reaosn am learning is to how can I get individual access to labels and linkbuttons while hiding and showing their visibility based on some conditions in the database. For instance am fetching a book in the database snd to determine whether the book is online, in store or in library it displays label and button depending on the mention condition. So kindly any help will assist thanks a lot

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal How good are you at .net and C# perhaps I can share email with details of what I needed to solve and what have done so far. Its been giving me headache for now almost a month but once I cross the bridge the project will be done.

Comment: @HeKe can you post the portion of your code where you are getting the data from the database and binding it to the datagrid (or whatever UI control you are using) ?

Comment: @P.T. the code he's showing is from the link, which goes to a Microsoft example. There is little other code shown there and you have to read the whole article.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you. I am aware of the Microsoft Docs he has posted. He mentioned querying his database for a book, and then binding that data to his UI control and he wants to hook into with the ItemDatabound event. Similar to the example he posted, all he needs to do is cast the DataItem back to the original Type that was used during databinding and then can continue to apply the formatting he wants to do. If we could see his Databinding (the code he's using to retrieve the book from the database) then we may be able to provide the code needed to cast the DataItem to the right Type

Comment: See my answer below - I give a narrative and example as to how this works.

Comment: @P.T. AhI now see he's been putting important information in the comments. Always great when you have to read all the comments in order to get the whole question... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a great question, and like some time travel movie, I REALLY WISH someone had and did explain how this works. You note that sometimes the "data source" of the datalist works, and sometimes it does not, and why is this so???

So, the data source comes from WHEN the control was "binded" or spoon fed the data source.

So, on page load, there is most likly some code that set-up and "binds" the data control. Or, it might be that a sqldatasource was dropped into the web page, but AGAIN, either way?

The page load will then trigger the row data bound event.
(ItemDataBound).

So, first BIG tip:

The e.Item.DataItem used IS ONLY available DURING the data bind process. That quite much means at data bind time and the ItemDataBound event.

So, WHEN you shove a data source INTO the GridView, Datalist, ListView, repeater etc controls? And use the data bound event (the name varies a wee bit, bu they all do the same thing), then the DataItemView is ONLY available DURING the row data bind process and hence you are 100% free to use that data source DURING the data bind event - BUT NOT AFTER!!!!!

After, binding has occured, you find that the the dataitem (and control datasoruce is NOW null!!!!). This is VERY different then desktop versions of such controls in .net (in desktop land, you actually can get/use/see the ACTUAL object used for each row!!! - and they persist!!!!

In web land, that data source is converted to a DataRowView.

However, what is the basic knowledge here?

Well, it means that your data control does NOT have to display or hide all of the columns from the database, but you ARE STILL FREE to use those additional columns for things like tax calculations, or for formatting controls based on OTHER columns that you have in the datasource BUT ARE NOT DISPLAYED!!!

And you see BOATLOADS of examples posted where people use hidden fields and all kinds of tricks, and they did that because they DID NOT KNOW the above!!!

Now, it not clear if you want to use a "datalist" control. They tend to be good for say one reocrd, or say several records in a "card like" view - not a table like layout.

So, for a table like layout, I suggest using ListView (most flexible), or for simple, and not too fancy, then use GridView.

But, DataList, listView, GridView, Repeater ? They all of this Row bound (or Item bound) event (they all are VERY close named).

And as noted, JUST like your question, in most cases this event can be used for addtional formatting.

Lets do this with a GridView - (since it easy).

So, say we have a grid of hotel names, but I want to highlight in say blue color ONLY hotels that are active. But I ALSO do NOT want to display the "active" column from the data base in that grid.

So, say this simple markup:

```
        <style> .MyCenter {text-align:center;}</style>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID"  cssclass="table" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"                />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" ItemStyle-Width="120px"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View"   >
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="MyCenter"/>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="MyCenter" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="bView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Now, our code to load, we have this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

So, lets use the ItemDataBound event (RowdataBound for Gridview) to highlight the Hotel name and descrption ONLY for Hotels that are active. As noted, we do NOT display "Active" column in the gridview, but with Row data bound event, we still have use of the FULL row.

So, we can add this code to the Row data bound event.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // get the full data row used for binding
            DataRowView OneRow = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

            // lets highlist the hotel name + description               
            if ((bool)OneRow["Active"])
            {
                e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            } 

            // that button is not centered "vertical", so lets do that
            Button btn = e.Row.FindControl("bView") as Button;
            DataControlFieldCell g = btn.Parent as DataControlFieldCell;
            g.Style.Add("vertical-align", "middle");
        }
    }
```

And now we we get this:

[image]

So, what about the view item click? For that we could use a datalist as you have, and we could then hide the grid, display the datalist, and we would be quite much on our way with a grid to edit items, then right?

Coffee break - I'll be back in a bit to add the view + datalist to see/view/edit one  item.

## Ok, part 2 - using a datalist to display above click

Ok, so lets drop in a data list - with a div area (to hide and show).

So, ok, now our data list we drop in.

```
   <div id="MyEditArea" runat="server" style="width:44%;margin-left:35px;padding:8px;border:solid;display:none">

        <asp:Datalist ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" >
            <ItemTemplate>
         <style>
            .iForm label {display:inline-block;width:95px}
            .iForm input {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}                
            .iForm textarea {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}     
            .iForm input[type=checkbox] {margin-right:6px}
        </style>
        <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
                <label>HotelName</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' width="280" />  <br />
                <label>First Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>City</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Province</label><asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>'
                    f="Province" Width="75"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;width:420px " class="iForm">
            <label>Description</label> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Height="150px" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' ></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' Text=" Active" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" Checked='<%# Eval("Balcony") %>' Text=" Has Balcony" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSmoking" Checked='<%# Eval("Smoking") %>' Text=" Smoking Area" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>



        <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
      <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:10px" />

     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Datalist>
```

And now our button click for the grid view - to display that one data list control + data.

Hum, started writing some code routine, so lets clean this up a bit.

Ok, so we now have this to load + format the gridview.

```
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // get the full data row used for binding
            DataRowView OneRow = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            // lets highlist the hotel name + description               
            if ((bool)OneRow["Active"])
            {
                e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }

            // button is not centered "vertical", so lets do that
            Button btn = e.Row.FindControl("bView") as Button;
            DataControlFieldCell g = btn.Parent as DataControlFieldCell;
            g.Style.Add("vertical-align", "middle");
        }
    }
    void CenterControl(Control c)
    {
        DataControlFieldCell g = c.Parent as DataControlFieldCell;
        g.Style.Add("vertical-align", "middle");
    }


    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And for the button click on the grid, we have this now:

```
    protected void bView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int? PKID = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"] as int?;

        // Now load our datalist
        string strSQL = "SELECT * from tblHotelsA WHERE ID = " + PKID;
        DataList1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        DataList1.DataBind();

        // hide grid, show edit area
        GridView1.Style.Add("display", "none");
        MyEditArea.Style.Add("display", "normal");
    }
```

So, now when we click on a row, we hide grid, show our data list control, and we now see/have this:

[image]

And just like the grid view, lets highlight the hotelname and description as  light grey. Once again, we now use the data list row data bound event.

Say, this:

Note how we don't use .cells for the data list, but have to use find control.

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) |
            e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataRowView gData = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

            if ((bool)gData["Active"])
            {
                TextBox txtHotel = e.Item.FindControl("txtHotel") as TextBox;
                txtHotel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
                TextBox txtDescript = e.Item.FindControl("txtNotes") as TextBox;
                txtDescript.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
        }
    }
```

And, you do have to check for item, and "alternating" item.

But, now, when we click on a grid row, we get this:

[image]